# Source-ing an .R script within a function and passing a variable through (RODBC)

Tags: r

I have encountered a bit of a hiccup in something I'm working on. Suppose I have the following simple example. Let...

```
v <- c(606:608) ## Some vector of integers
```

I also, have a **separate script** written (let's just call it `foo.R`) which has something like (uses the `RODBC` package):

```
um <- sqlQuery(artemis,paste("select * from port.tdtf_VaR_Unmatched (",LatestModelRun,")",sep=""))
```

Now suppose I want to run the following loop function:

```
test <- function() {
 for (i in 1:length(v)) {
  LatestModelRun <- v[i]
  source("C:/R/foo.r")
  print(unmatched)} }

test() ## Run it
```

When I do this, I get the following error:
`Error in paste("\n\tselect * from port.tdtf_VaR_Unmatched (", LatestModelRun,  : 
  object 'LatestModelRun' not found`

So, somehow it's not reading in the `LatestModelRun` variable defined within the `test` function.

Here's the `traceback()`:

```
7: paste("\n\tselect * from port.tdtf_VaR_Unmatched (", LatestModelRun, 
   ")\n\twhere [PortfolioProduct] not in ('REC - Generic','REC - Green-e NY')\n\torder by [PortfolioProduct], [Year]", 
   sep = "")
6: odbcQuery(channel, query, rows_at_time)
5: sqlQuery(artemis, paste("\n\tselect * from port.tdtf_VaR_Unmatched (", 
   LatestModelRun, ")\n\twhere [PortfolioProduct] not in ('REC - Generic','REC - Green-e NY')\n\torder by [PortfolioProduct], [Year]", 
   sep = ""))
4: eval.with.vis(expr, envir, enclos)
3: eval.with.vis(ei, envir)
2: source("C:/R/foo.r")
1: test()
```

Anybody have an idea as to what I'm doing wrong??

Any help is much appreciated!! Thanks!!

Comment: I had this as an answer, but I decided I wasn't too sure about it, so I'll leave it as a comment instead. One simplistic solution would be to call the contents of `foo.r` as a function, rather than a script.

Comment: Environment issue?  In general I think @joran is right and you should call this as a function so you don't abuse globals.  But if you're stuck with this approach, try explicit global assignment and evaluation.

Comment: By default the `source`'d code is evaluated in the global environment.  Try setting `local=TRUE`, which will evaluate the code in the calling environment.

Comment: @gsk3 - Yeah, it appears `?source` defaults to evaluating in the global environment, but in the OP's traceback it appears the error may occur inside an altered environment (`eval.with.vis`).

Answer (score 40, accepted):

As I said in my comment, the `source`'d code is evaluated in the global environment by default. Set `local=TRUE` to evaluate the code in the calling environment.

```
test <- function() {
  for (i in 1:length(v)) {
    LatestModelRun <- v[i]
    source("C:/R/foo.r", local=TRUE)
    print(unmatched)
  }
}
v <- c(606:608)
test()
# [1] "select * from port.tdtf_VaR_Unmatched (606)"
# [1] "select * from port.tdtf_VaR_Unmatched (607)"
# [1] "select * from port.tdtf_VaR_Unmatched (608)"
```

where `foo.r` contains:

```
unmatched <-
  paste("select * from port.tdtf_VaR_Unmatched (",LatestModelRun,")",sep="")
```

Answer (score 10):

Joshua's answer is sweet & simple. I have a variant that allows you to be more explicit in how you pass parameters to the script:

```
test <- function() {
  for (i in 1:length(v)) {
    e <- new.env()
    e$LatestModelRun <- v[i]
    sys.source('c:/R/foo.R', e)
    print(e$unmatched)
  }
}
```

This uses the cousin to `source`; `sys.source` that allows you specify the environment.
The environment can actually also be a list, **so if you don't need any result variables** from the script,
you can simply passing in a list with the parameters you need:

```
sys.source('c:/R/bar.R', list(someparam=42, anotherparam=1:10))
```

Answer (score -1):

Variables set in a function are not global, unless set by `<<-`, so wouldn't this work?

```
test <- function() {
 for (i in 1:length(v)) {
  LatestModelRun <<- v[i]
  source("C:/R/foo.r")
  print(unmatched)
 }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I have a good idea. It is not needed to write the path of the "foo.r" function as: "C:/R/foo.r"
You can if it is within your package, write it as:
"source("~/mat.r", local=TRUE)".

Best
.
Ali

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35753460)

Comment: They weren't asking about file paths, and they don't seem to be working on a package. If they _were_ working on a package, sourcing other scripts would be an anti-pattern