# R in production - working down an SQL database in batched groups until database is exhausted?

Tags: sql, r, production, dbplyr

**Background**

I am having a problem with batch processing, of an R script (approx. 1000 lines) which requires calls to a SQL backend to pick up data. The data is pulled into R from SQL via odbc, and I do have writing privileges to the backend. I have stored as much as possible in the backend to reduce local memory usage.

However, an issue is a caused by a few memory intensive processes, such as a huge number of correlations, and imputations for time-series structures. When the script is applied to the entire dataset, this takes up a lot of local memory, that is not discounting the size of the database in general just to pull the data.

**Script and data structures**

My script  is designed so that batches of 20 'item groups', with up to 100 items in each group, are used to get the time-series data for each item in the group. This data is are stored as a nested  dataframe relative to the 'item group' (see image below), and is used throughout the script to facilitate parallel processing on the selected batch.
[image]

Obviously if I expand the nested table to allow 2000+ 'item groups', I will crash my computer just loading the data, before the memory intensive processes are applied. So I though the best approach may be to create a grouping variable in the backend table (numbered 1 to 200) for each chunk/batch I want to call into the R script.

**The Question**

I can also use the backend to work down the chunking/batch group variable, removing groups as they are processed. My problem is now how to make the script run until all the chucks have been processed, either directly in the R script or in shell. What is the best approach for this? Is there any examples of working through a database like this.

I appreciate that this is more of an approach question than coding, but I would be happy with any coding examples that may be useful as well as approach advice. I am new to productising R code so anything would be helpful.

Thank you for reading.

FYI I do not have the luxury of using cloud computing at this time.

Comment: Why the [tag:shell] tag?

Comment: I think I understand your dilemma, but I don't know how we can help, we don't know the data or your code. You talk about "memory intensive processes": the fact that you load this frame with 2000 groups and 15-45k rows each suggests that you think you need all of them in R at a time. What is it about your code that means you must load all of that at once?

Comment: Sorry I may not have been explicit enough, I'm saying I cannot load 2000 groups, as it will crash, which is why I want to make the code do batch/chunks. I do, however, need to process 2000+ groups.

Comment: Then perhaps just load 5-10 at a time, do each chunk, then upload/save the results, delete the variables, and lather/rinse/repeat.

Comment: @r2evans I removed the shell tag, I thought it was relevant to calling the script multiple times. I'm not looking for a specific code example more the best framework, and any example code that would help conceptualise that. For example could I loop over the a script while checking the backend.

Comment: A {mcve] is a great start when asking SQL questions.

Comment: @r2evans I am thinking of keeping the chunks as 20 item groups, but that would be 100+ calls of the script. So is not practical in production unless I can automate (maybe by looping) by using the chunk grouping variable in the database.

Comment: I'm really not certain how to help you, Comte. Can you execute your script on a computer/server with more RAM? Is your database SQL Server with R-Services enabled? Can any of your "memory intensive processes" be translated to raw SQL? We know _nothing_ here. I understand it's a hard problem, and it's hard to convey it well in a forum like this, but that does not make it any less unlikely to answer knowing nothing about the data or your processes.

Comment: Firstly thank you for your responses, I certainly realise now this could have been framed much better, and I may need to rework the question. I expect to dock the script later (server side), but right now I need to be able to run it locally (16gb ram). I did not realise you could enable SQL to use R, very useful information. Although I couldn't use that now, I need to call the data to be processed from SQL in to R, and I think I want to create a temporary table that monitors the chunks. So I guess I some how need to loop of the script, I think I may have found the answer.

Comment: I believe I want something like this, calling my script as a function, that way I can iterate over it and the SQL table with the variables in it. I will update the question and answer afterwards. Thank you for your thoughts, I will certainly try to be better in questions in the future.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41729469/r-script-as-a-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For iterating over large datasets, I use the modulus of a numeric column.

For example, the following code will subset to (approximately) one tenth of your dataset:

```r
large_remote_table = tbl(db_con, ...)

subset_remote_table = large_remote_table %>%
  filter(numeric_column %% 10 == 0)
```

What should you use as a numeric column? If your dataset already has some kind of numeric identities, then these are a good choice. Otherwise, I recommend you modify your input dataset to include a row number column. Many SQL flavors have a build in row number function.

We can then iterate over all the subsets using a for loop:

```r
number_subsets = 2000

large_remote_table = tbl(db_con, ...)

output_list = list()

for(ii in 1:number_subsets){
  this_subset = large_remote_table %>%
    filter(row_number %% number_subsets == ii)

  # further processing of subset

  # store result
  output_list[ii] = results_from_processing_of_subset
}
```